# PS C:\Users\crash> wsl Доступ к этому файлу из системы отсутствует

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell, wsl, wsl2

Всем привет!
Буквально сегодня накотил новую винду и не могу пользоваться wsl.
при вводе wsl или любых других комманд с wsl получаю ошибку
Доступ к этому файлу из системы отсутствует.

Comment: У Вас скорее всего нет wsl в path. Или же отключена служба wsl.

Answer (score 1):

Если при попытке запуска WSL возникает ошибка, проверьте, что служба WSL запущена. Для этого откройте PowerShell от имени администратора и выполните команду wsl --list --verbose . Если служба WSL не запускается, попробуйте выполнить команду wsl --set-default-version 2 для обновления версии WSL